# Get attributes of a empty child node

Tags: xslt-1.0

I want to transform a old HTML4 code to have closed tags in order to achieve compatibility with WCAG.

I have a lot of anchors without content, used as internal links, like

```
<h3> <a id="julio" name="julio"></a>Julio 2015</h3>
```

For reasons I do not understand, some browsers do not understand the self-enclosed tag, and interpret it as the start of an anchor (without end).

```
<h3> <a id="julio" name="julio"/a>Julio 2015</h3>
```

Then, I want to delete empty anchors and move the attributes to the parent tag:

```
<h3 id="julio" name="julio">Julio 2015</h3>
```

The tool I have to use only supports XSLT 1.0

How can I get it?

Comment: Wouldn't this be easier to solve by changing the output method to `html`?

Comment: No, we have output method as 'html' now and even some labels that we had closed, became open labels after the transformation. We need to have self-closing labels.

Comment: I am afraid this is confusing. I thought you wanted to eliminate self-closing tags.

Comment: No. I want to have all tags closed, in order to pass WCAG test, but some browser don´t support anchor self-closed tags :-).
So, I want to pass anchor id & name attributes to its parent (h3 in the example).

Comment: What good will they do there?

Comment: EDIT.
No. I want to have all tags closed, in order to pass WCAG test, but some browser don´t support anchor self-closed tags :-).
So, I want to pass anchor id & name attributes to its parent (h3 in the example).
Another solution would be, with the 'xml' output method, to left open only the empty anchor tags (<a></a>, not self-closed <a/>), but I do not know how to get it.
These anchors are mark destination into the page (with id="destination"), not origin (with href = "#destination")

Comment: Perhaps you could simply fill empty `a` elements with a space? That would be very easy to do (and also make much more sense to me).